# Possibility to deprecate enum constants?

Tags: java, enums, deprecated

Is it possible to use the `@Deprecated` annotation on enum constants?

Comment: Hello, couldn't you just try it and see yourself if it works ?

Comment: Because I like to get/share ideas from other people as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html), you will see the declaration:

```
@Target(value={CONSTRUCTOR,FIELD,LOCAL_VARIABLE,METHOD,PACKAGE,PARAMETER,TYPE})
```

which includes `FIELD`. If you click on `FIELD` you get to its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#FIELD) which states:

> Field declaration (includes enum constants)

So the answer is: yes it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that information including with Javadoc.

Comment: Thanks, I learnt a new way to retrieve information from java docs.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, put a `@Deprecated` annotation on them (uppercase). For example:

```
public enum Status {
OK,
ERROR,

@Deprecated
PROBLEM
}
```

> @Deprecated is an annotation that is read by the compiler, used to mark a method as deprecated to the compiler and will generate a deprecation compile-time warning if the method is used.
>
> @deprecated is a javadoc tag used to provide documentation about the deprecation. You can use it to explain why the method was deprecated and to suggest an alternative. It only makes sense to use this tag in conjunction to the @Deprecated annotation.

Comment: In that case, it should be @Deprecated with an uppercase before PROBLEM. I suggested an edit

Comment: Would you have a way to add a comment/helper next to the @Deprecated TAG (not the javadoc @deprecated)?